# Multiple and long seasonality for a SARIMA model in R

Tags: r, regression, arima, fourier-transform, multiple-seasonalities

While working on a big data set made of 10-minutes-points of information - i.e. `144` points per day, `1008` per week and `52560` per year - I encountered a few problem in R. The information concerns electricity load on a source substation during the year.

#### Multiple seasonality :

The data set clearly shows multiple seasonalities, which are daily, weekly and yearly. From [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47729/two-seasonal-periods-in-arima-using-r) I understood that R doesn't handle multiple seasonality within the ARIMA modeling functions.  I would really like to work with ARIMA models though, because my previous work is based on ARIMA models and I know approximatively how to translate a model into an equation.

#### Long seasonality :

Each of the seasonalities is of high value, with the shortest one being the daily seasonality at 144. Unfortunately from the SARIMA general equation which is
$\phi(B)\Phi(B^s)W_t = \theta(B)\Theta(B^s)Z_t$
I guessed that the maximum lag for a given model `SARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)144` is
$max((p+P*144), (q+Q*144))$

I would really like to try and fit models with values of P and/or Q greater than 1, but R doesn't allow me since the `maximum supported lag = 350`. To do so I found [this link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) which is really interesting and led to new functions in the forecast package by M. Hyndman, called `fourier` and `fourierf` which you can find [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/fourier). But since I am not a specialist in forecasting nor in statistics, I have some difficulties understanding how I can make this work.

---

The thing is I thing this whole fourier regressors package could help me a lot. From what I understood I could use it to simulate the long-seasonality of my data set, maybe use it to simulate multiple seasonality, and even more it could allow me to introduce exogenous variables - which are the `temperature` and (`public holiday + sundays`).
I also tried doing some regression following [this example](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/) but I couldn't make it work because :

```
Error in forecast.Arima(bestfit, xreg = fourierf(gas, K = 12, h = 1008)) : 
Number of regressors does not match fitted model
```

I really hope somebody can help me get a better understanding of these functions. Thanks.

**Edit :** So I tried my best with the fourier example given [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) but couldn't figure out how it handles the fitting. Here is the code (I copy-pasted M. Hyndman one and adapted to my data set - unsuccessfully) :

```
n <- 50000
m <- 144
y <- read.table("auch.txt", skip=1)
fourier <- function(t,terms,period)
{
  n <- length(t)
  X <- matrix(,nrow=n,ncol=2*terms)
  for(i in 1:terms)
  {
    X[,2*i-1] <- sin(2*pi*i*t/period)
    X[,2*i] <- cos(2*pi*i*t/period)
  }
  colnames(X) <- paste(c("S","C"),rep(1:terms,rep(2,terms)),sep="")
  return(X)
}

library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(y[1:n,1], order=c(2,1,5), seasonal=c(1,2,8), xreg=cbind(fourier(1:n,4,m),fourier(1:n,4,1008)))
plot(forecast(fit, h=14*m, xreg=cbind(fourier(n+1:(14*m),4,m), fourier(n+1:(14*m),4,1008))))
```

So I wanted to "force" the model to be a `SARIMA(2,1,5)(1,2,8)[144]` but when I type `arimod`this is the result of the Arima fitting :

```
> fit  
Series: y[1:n, 1] , 
ARIMA(2,1,5)                  

sigma^2 estimated as 696895:  log likelihood=-407290.2  
AIC=814628.3   AICc=814628.3   BIC=814840
```

It doesn't even take into consideration the seasonal part of the model, and I don't know much about the range the AIC values can take, but it seems way too high to be a good fitting model right there. I think it all comes down to my misunderstanding of the use of Fourier terms as regressors, but I can't figure out why.

**Edit 2 :** Also I can't seem to be able to add another exogenous variable to the Arima function. I need to use `temperature` - probably as a lead - to fit the `SARIMAX` model, but as soon as I write this :

```
fit <- Arima(y[1:n,1], order=c(2,1,5), seasonal=c(1,2,8), xreg=cbind(fourier(1:n,4,m),fourier(1:n,4,1008), tmp[1:n]))
plot(forecast(fit, h=14*m, xreg=cbind(fourier(n+1:(14*m),4,m),fourier(n+1:(14*m),4,1008), tmp[n+1:(14*m)])))
```

Nothing is plotted besides the initial data set. There is no forecast while without `tmp` as an `xreg` I still get some results.

Answer (score 2):

Structure your data as an `msts` (multiple seasonality time series), where you can specify

`msts(your_data, start=2010, seasonal.periods=c(144,1008,52560))`.

Then, when fitting fourier terms for seasonality you must specify the three seasonal periods on fourier function:

`reg <- fourier(your_data, K=c(i,n,j))`, this will look for fourier terms over each seasonal period.

You can loop through a linear regression where the explanatory variables are the fourier terms to obtain the best fit and then put them into the ARIMA model as regressors. These will be equivalent, because ARIMA with regressors actually is a regression with ARIMA errors.

`auto.arima(your_data, xreg= as.matrix(reg), seasonal= F)`

Don´t forget to specify `seasonal=F` to avoid maximum supported `lag = 350`.